# asp.net: DetailsView control not interpreting html

Tags: asp.net, detailsview

I have a asp.net detailsview control on a page. I've noticed that it always displays the raw text from my database field, it doesn't interpret the html in the text -- so it displays < b>mytext< /b> instead of just mytext in bold.

Is there anyway to get the control to interpret the html in the data being returned

Regards
melt

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Can you post the code of your control?  The basics are you need to set the HtmlEncode property to false.  This is due to a difference in how labels and textboxes handle encoding, something meant to protect you from malicious scripts someone may have entered in these fields.

If you have it set to auto-generate fields (default), you'll need to change to [BoundField](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.boundfield.aspx)s or [TemplateField](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.templatefield.aspx)s instead and set the offending field's [HtmlEncode Property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.boundfield.htmlencode.aspx) to false.

You can see a [code sample of the individual fields in MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb288033.aspx), here's a simplified example:

```
<asp:DetailsView runat="server" AutoGenerateRows="False">
  <Fields>
    <asp:BoundField DataField="ProductName" HeaderText="Product" />
    <asp:BoundField DataField="CategoryName" HeaderText="Category" />
    <asp:BoundField DataField="HTMLField" HeaderText="HTML" HtmlEncode="false" />
  </Fields>
</asp:DetailsView>
```